# Listing all directories, subdirectories and files in SSH server (Java)(JSch)

Tags: java, linux, ssh, jsch, directory-listing

I'm working on Java GUI application that connects to a ssh server and executes remote commands on the server. I'm willing to use JSch Library.

Problem is, I couldn't find a solution to execute a linux command via a JSch session, which will list all directories, subdirectories and files in a SSH server.

Since I have not made so much modifications on the JSch's example code, yet, you can consider this code as mine: http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html

Comment: You have some example code that connects to a remote system and runs a command. What is your specific problem?

Comment: @Kenster Hi, my problem is I don't know how to do recursively directory/file listing in SSH server.

Comment: If the remote system is a unix system; simply try "find /" - and be prepared for **a lot** of output. Besides: on a first glance, this is not a programming question. You are asking: how can I "find" all files on a system; the fact that you want to do that via Java doesn't matter for that. In that sense: superuser.com might be the better place for the first part of your question.

Comment: @Jägermeister Hi, If you know WinSCP, I'm willing to develop an app that lists the dirs/subdirs/files in the way WinSCP does. So I think what you have offered will output so many things, which will be hard to parse. So, I see it is not a good idea of me to list "all" on the server. Instead, I should list only current directory's file/subdir contents. Any advisement on that?

Comment: @orhan7 Yes. Turn to superuser.com. And besides: **man find** The find command knows --depth for example.

Comment: Note that commands like `find` and `ls` are unix/linux commands, not "ssh server" commands. They'll only work if the server is a unix server. If your utility is for browsing or manipulating files, you should consider using SFTP rather than running commands over plain ssh.